# Selected Intervals of dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I am working with MySQL. I am trying to get the nights of a booking that belong to each interval in a group of intervals of dates. But there are some intervals that are preferred over others and therefore I will take as many nights for **the preferred** intervals as possible and fill the gaps with the **not preferred interval **. To illustrate this I will show it here:

Given the dates:

check in => 2016-01-16

check out =>   2016-02-08

total nights => 24

```
      Preferred |  date_from   |  date_to   | Nights     
----------------------------------------------------
     1          |  2016-01-15  | 2016-01-17 | 2
     1          |  2016-02-03  | 2016-02-10 | 6
     1          |  2016-01-20  | 2016-01-25 | 6
     0          |  2016-01-20  | 2016-01-31 | 2 (2016-01-26 and 2016-01-31 because the other nights are covered by a preferred period)
     1          |  2016-01-27  | 2016-01-30 | 4
     0          |  2016-01-15  | 2016-01-17 | 0 (these dates are covered by a the first interval which is a preferred interval )
     0          |  2016-02-01  | 2016-02-10 | 2 (just 2016-02-01 and 2016-02-02 because 03 - 08 are covered by the second interval which is a preferred interval)
     0          |  2016-01-18  | 2016-01-19 | 2
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: because 03 - 08 are covered by the second interval OR  03 -10 #typo

Comment: @diEcho I don't think it's a typo 03-08 are covered by second interval the 09 and 10 are ignored because it's outside of checkin/checkout range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have a table with columns Preferred,date_from,date_to and you're just trying to calculate # of nights.

You can try this query.

```
SET @checkin = '2016-01-16';
SET @checkout = '2016-02-08';

SELECT T0.preferred,T0.date_from,T0.date_to,IFNULL(NIGHTS.nights,0) as Nights
FROM YourTable T0
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT T1.preferred,T1.date_from,T1.date_to,COUNT(*) AS Nights
       FROM YourTable AS T1
       INNER JOIN
        (SELECT (@checkin + INTERVAL n DAY) as singleday
         FROM numbers 
         WHERE (@checkin + INTERVAL n DAY) <= @checkout)DAYS1
      ON DAYS1.singleday BETWEEN T1.date_from AND T1.date_to
      WHERE T1.preferred = 1
      OR NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1
       FROM YourTable AS T
       WHERE T.preferred = 1
         AND DAYS1.singleday BETWEEN T.date_from AND T.date_to
       )
    GROUP BY T1.preferred,T1.date_from,T1.date_to
    )NIGHTS
ON T0.preferred = NIGHTS.preferred
AND T0.date_from = NIGHTS.date_from
AND T0.date_to = NIGHTS.date_to
WHERE
    T0.date_from <= @checkout
AND T0.date_to >= @checkin
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d64344/10
you can replace `@checkout` and `@checkin` occurrences with your actual checkin and check out times.
and you can replace `YourTable` occurrences with your actual table name

Oh yeah in the sqlfiddle i have included a table called Numbers with column `n` that contains numbers from 0 counting upward to whatever maximum number of possible days of stay.  You need to create this table as well.

to create table numbers use the below

```
CREATE TABLE numbers AS
SELECT a.n+b.n+c.n+d.n+e.n+f.n+g.n+h.n+i.n as n
FROM
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1)a,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 2)b,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 4)c,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 8)d,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 16)e,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 32)f,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 64)g,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 128)h,
(SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 256)i;
```

- explaination of the query

1) subquery DAYS1 returns all single dates
   from @checkin to @checkout range

2) T1 is Joined with DAYS1 WHERE
   preferred is 1 OR that there doesnt exist a preferred row that covers
   the DAYS1's dates

3) then we do a COUNT(*) GROUP BY
   preferred,date_from,date_to to get count of single days

4) Then we call our result NIGHTS

5) Then T0 is LEFT JOINED with NIGHTS to get even rows that have 0 nights

6) And only return T0 rows that intercept out @checkin/@checkout range.

**UPDATE** If you table is too large you can try and narrow down your subqueries with only rows you're interested in like this

```
SET @checkin = '2016-01-16';
SET @checkout = '2016-02-08';

SELECT T0.preferred,T0.date_from,T0.date_to,IFNULL(NIGHTS.nights,0) as Nights
FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE date_from <= @checkout AND date_to >= @checkin) T0
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT T1.preferred,T1.date_from,T1.date_to,COUNT(*) AS Nights
       FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE date_from <= @checkout AND date_to >= @checkin) AS T1
       INNER JOIN
        (SELECT (@checkin + INTERVAL n DAY) as singleday
         FROM numbers 
         WHERE (@checkin + INTERVAL n DAY) <= @checkout)DAYS1
      ON DAYS1.singleday BETWEEN T1.date_from AND T1.date_to
      WHERE T1.preferred = 1
      OR NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1
       FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE date_from <= @checkout AND date_to >= @checkin) AS T
       WHERE T.preferred = 1
         AND DAYS1.singleday BETWEEN T.date_from AND T.date_to
       )
    GROUP BY T1.preferred,T1.date_from,T1.date_to
    )NIGHTS
ON T0.preferred = NIGHTS.preferred
AND T0.date_from = NIGHTS.date_from
AND T0.date_to = NIGHTS.date_to
;
```

Comment: It works but my table has to many rows and it is very slow because in the production environment the view "YourTable" (yes, it is a view with many columns that I omitted in order not to complicate the example) has thousands of rows. It is amazing however that you came up with the solution to the example in such an elegant way and that fast! Thank you very much sir!!

Comment: maybe you add the 
`WHERE
    date_from <= @checkout
AND date_to >= @checkin`
to the inner queries as well so that it narrows down the results before it starts joining

Comment: Check my answer again, i updated it with the query at the very bottom that tries to narrow down the resultset  before it tries to do anything with them.

Comment: if you create index for date_from and date_in columns it should be fast with thousands of rows

Comment: Yes, I did and also I added other parameters to make it even por narrow but even so it takes up to 17  secs and that is only a part of the complete query. I have interval identifiers that are related to prices and multiply these times the number of nights in each interval to get a correct price and then other stuff! But it is still slow!!

Comment: CREATE INDEX date_from_index ON YourActualTable (date_from);
CREATE INDEX date_to_index ON YourActualTable (date_to);

Comment: if you CREATE INDEX it'll be fast

Comment: I thought they were there already because I had added them to the table before but I forgot that I had deleted the database ad copied again from a back up that did not have the indexes. Yes, it takes 1.065 secs now! I will incorporate this to the procedure I have and test it again! I will let you know about the results after I perform all the tests!

Comment: I just updated my answer to a version that doesn't join with numbers table twice, the sqlfiddle i have is old it joins with numbers table twice.  the query posted in answer should be faster than the sqlfiddle one

Comment: I have tested it with a huge view (yourtable) and the results are wrong. Sorry but I could not test it sooner with the production data!